# Use the img-tag with JSP

Tags: html, image, jsp

I'm trying to display an image on my webpage, that is made with jsp/html. When I use the following code, I get an error that says:

> "Bad value "  " for attribute src on element img: DOUBLE_WHITESPACE in PATH.

```
<img src="<%=item.getPicture()%>" width="100">
```

The function `getPicture()` returns an URL to the image that I need.

Why doesn't this work?

Comment: could you please share your **getPicture** method? as error says you have some bad characters in the url.

Comment: Where exactly do you get this error? This is a typical W3 HTML validation error message. If that's indeed true, you'd logically show the generated HTML output in your question instead of the JSP source code in order to investigate the culprit. So, rightclick page in browser, *View Source*, find the JSP-generated HTML line and put it in the question instead of the JSP source code.

Comment: I get the error in my NetBeans-file, so I don't think the jsp-generated html is the problem. The getPicture()-method works with img in my other calls.